# AngularJS with RequireJS routing removes hash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, requirejs, http-status-code-404

I'm using Angular Routes to determine the view to be displayed to the user as follows:

```
define(['angular', './app'], function(angular, app) {
    'use strict';
    return angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).
    config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl:'assets/partials/partial1.html',
                controller: 'MyCtrl1'
            }).when('/mada', {
                templateUrl:'assets/partials/partial2.html',
                controller: 'MyCtrl2'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

    });

});
```

At the moment, the routing works but only like this: localhost/#/mada or localhost/#/
I would like to be able to see localhost/mada

I am aware that adding

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

would get rid of the hash. But this still doesn't enable a user to go to: localhost/mada as this returns a server 404.

Can this be achieved? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are not using server side language then put this code in html head.

```
<base href="/">
```

like :

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

and put this in config block:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

if you are using server side language then use this code:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

instead of

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

and and put this code in config block:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```